# Return array of values from object based on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, lodash

I have an object that looks like this[image]

I would like to return an array of wsnames based on altnames. For example, I provide an array `["AAVEETH", "AAVEXBT"]` and get back `["AAVE/ETH", "AAVE/XBT"]`.

I figured out how to use `lodash` `__.filter` like this

```
 const wsnames = _.filter(
    obj,
    (item) => item.altname === 'AAVEETH' || item.altname === 'AAVEXBT'
  )
```

but this only returns the full object entry. Also, my input array won't be known beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First turn the values of the object into an array of values with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). Now you can use array methods like [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the unwanted values and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with only the `wsname` properties.

```
const wsNames = Object.values(obj)
  .filter(({ altname }) => altname === 'AAVEETH' || altname === 'AAVEXBT')
  .map(({ wsname }) => wsname);
```

Now you can turn this logic into a function in which you pass the object you want to filter from and an array of `altname` values that you want to get the `wsname` values from.

```
const getWsNames = (obj, altNames) => Object.values(obj)
  .filter(({ altname }) => altNames.includes(altname))
  .map(({ wsname }) => wsname);

const wsNames = getWsNames(obj, ['AAVEETH', 'AAVEXBT']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Object.values` and `array.filter` to achieve this.

```
let arr = ["AAVEETH", "AAVEXBT"]
let masterObj = [....] // your object having all data
result = []
arr.forEach(i => {
 let found =  Object.values(masterObj).filter(i => i.altname)[0]
  if(found){
    result.push(i.wsname)
  }
})
```

In above code i am just looping on your `altname` array on behalf of which you want to get `wsname` array and in that i am using `object.values` to get all `values` as `array` and then i am doing filteration to get the wsname of the matching object that have matching `altname`